# Let $S$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains infinitely many points.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

I'm unsure how to do either part. Can someone please help explain this to me?

Comment: There's a good way to do this using Real Induction, given [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/instructors_guide_shorter.pdf) (Theorem 10). However, there is a good chance your instructor is not familiar with real induction, so I don't recommend it. (In fact, I doubt _you_ are familiar with it; it's explained in the first few pages of the paper.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is pretty much self explanatory -- if you choose $s_1, s_2, \ldots s_M$ for some finite $M$ then you will always have infinitely many more points to choose from for the rest of your sequence, so you can construct your sequence formally by induction. For the second part, let $[a,b]$ be an interval that contains your bounded set, and consider splitting the interval in half. Then one of the half intervals contains infinitely many points from your set. So then split that half interval in half, and so on. This process, if carried on ad infinitum, will yield a limit point for your infinite bounded set. Technically this relies on the completeness of the real line.

Comment: The real line is compact now??

Comment: I stated explicitly that $[a,b]$ was an interval  that contained the BOUNDED set $S$. So no, I'm not saying the real line is compact. Just complete.

Comment: Maybe I'm hallucinating. Because I could have sworn I read the last line as "Technically this relies on the compactness of the real line" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part (a): Just do what the suggestion says.

Hint for part (b): You have used the hypothesis that $S$ is infinite. You have not yet used that the hypothesis that it is bounded. Do you know a theorem about bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has to do with limit points?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for second part: For any $A\subset{\mathbb R}$, let ${\rm diam}(A) = \sup_{x,y\in A}{|x-y|}$. Derive a sequence of sets starting from $S$, where in each step, first two new sets of previous set is constructed such that diam of each be at most half of diam of previous one and, then one of these two set which is infinite is chosen. Using this procedure, a sequence of non-empty sets like $S=S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3, ...$ can be constructed where $2{\rm diam}(S_{n})\le {\rm diam}(S_{n-1})$, for any $n\in {\mathbb N}$. Continue this argument and use the fact that ${\mathbb R}$ is complete, i.e Cauchy sequences are convergent in ${\mathbb R}$.